# Beginning Spring 3 and error executing app

Tags: maven, ubuntu, spring-3, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've tried running the [Spring 3 Hello World tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-hello-world-example/) on my Ubuntu machine and have run into a few issues.

First, I'm working on the Springsource ToolSuite 3.1.0 release, and have Maven installed on my machine.  I already went thru a Java App with Maven tutorial on the same site.

First, isn't Maven supposed to resolve dependency issues?  When I wrote

```
import org.springframework.*;
```

I got an error stating that the library was not able to be found, so I had to add the JAR itself manually to the build path to solve that issue.  This was despite many .m2/REPO library paths existing on the build path wizard.

`mvn --version` returns

```
jason@asus:~/IDE/springsource/sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/plugins$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.7-03050702-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Secondly, when executing from the command line, I get this printout:

```
jason@asus:~/Documents/workspace-sts-/SpringExample$ java -cp target/SpringExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.jasonjohns.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:492)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:484)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Just to be sure, I checked the STS/plugins folder and there is an `org.springframework.beans_3.1.1.RELEASE.jar` there.

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jasonjohns</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!--  Spring 3 Dependencies  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What you got in your pom.xml?

Comment: @alex.p, added the pom.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try navigating to your project's location in a terminal and then do `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. This will (re)generate Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite-specific files - essentially creating .classpath and .project files (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html).

The .classpath is essentially your build path and by running **eclipse:eclipse** maven will generate it for you based on the contents of your pom.xml.

Once done, refresh the project in Eclipse/STS. Making sure build automatically is ticked (Project->Build Automatically).

Comment: There was one issue regarding a misspelling, but the project refresh did the trick.  The app runs via Run As->Java Application, but throws a NoClassDefFoundError that org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory is not found.